# Is there some trick to AllowEmptyString

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've never been able to get the AllowEmptyString validation attribute to work.

This:

```
function Get-InputString(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string][AllowEmptyString]$Str
)
{
    $Str
}
```

Results in this:

```
PS C:\> Get-InputString ''
Unable to find type [AllowEmptyString]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:2 char:71
+     [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string][AllowEmptyString] <<<< $Str
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (AllowEmptyString:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the parens on the attribute. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347600.aspx

```
function Get-InputString
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [String]
        $Str
    )

    $Str
}
```

Comment: Took me a minute to see that. Instead of copying/pasting your repro I was typing out the attribute and subconsciously typing out the parens. Sorry about my useless comment.

Comment: Thanks.  It would have been nice if they had the parens in the sample in the PowerShell help.

Comment: I'm looking at the sample in about_advanced_functions and I see parens - where is the sample you're talking about that lacks the parens?

Comment: sorry, that should be about_functions_advanced_parameters

Comment: It looks like a doc error in the help included with Powershell. The online link referenced in this answer has the correct syntax.